# ¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra "Guarandinga?"

Tags: etimología, venezuela

Según esta [web](http://projetbabel.org/internet/venezonalismos.htm#G):

> Guarandinga.- Palabra proveniente de la zona de Barquisimeto que
>   nombra una situación o estado.

Pero quisiera saber el significado real y su procedencia.

Answer (score 4):

El sufijo americano *-inga* parece ser de origen africano. Al igual que -anga, -enga, -onga y otros similares, se usa para mostrar desdén o para desvalorizar. Otras palabras hispanoamericanas que terminan en _inga son *pinga* ("pene"), *mandinga* ("el demonio"), *catinga* ("hediondez") y *minga* (alguna festividad familar y desordenada).

La palabra *guarandinga* pudo haberse formado por creatividad popular, no encontré ninguna fuente muy segura al respecto. Es un término venezolano, aunque se usa también en Cuba y probablemente en Colombia. En términos generales se ha usado para designar cualquier objeto, evento o estado sin importancia y que a veces causa alguna molestia, por ejemplo una broma, algún objeto que se ha perdido o algo que se ha descompuesto. Actualmente también designa un autobús rural y hay al menos una localidad llamada La Guarandinga.

Hay quienes creen que deriva de la palabra *guaro* (el "loro" o "perico", un ave ruidosa y común), y otros opinan que deriva de *warandol*, que es una tela que se usaba para la confección de manteles y cortinas. En *[Archivos Venezolanos de Folklore](https://books.google.cl/books?id=oPHZAAAAMAAJ&q=guarandinga&dq=guarandinga&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjy1fvM-LDaAhVDE5AKHRwHDSQQ6AEIJjAA)*  se dice que cuando la gente compraba telas decía "no me venda esa guarandinga", refiriéndose al warandol. El nombre de este género probablemente es la deformación de alguna palabra o marca inglesa.

Answer (score 0):

'Guarandinga' no es una palabra barquisimetana, es una palabra caroreña.
La ciudad de Carora es conocida porque su gente se comunica con extrañas y antiguas palabras, cosa que se mantiene aún en la actualidad, además el acento caroreño es distinto al resto del Estado Lara, aún siendo del mismo Estado.
La proveniencia del dialecto parte de antíguos indígenas achaguas-caquetíos y colonizadores de la Gran Canaria.

En la página turística de Carora se puede consultar un [*Diccionario de Caroreñismos*](http://encarora.com.ve/diccionario.htm) donde se da la siguiente definición:

> GUARANDINGA
>
> Echar vainas, bromas, molestias.